# Color schemes good for the eyes

Tags: colors

Are there any common guidelines howto choose a color scheme (for example foreground/background color) for terminal, `emacs` etc. to minimize exhaustion of the eyes? If so, is there scientific evidence for such a guideline?

In particular are there ready to use eye-friendly color schemes for `urxvt`and `emacs`?

**Edit:**

It would be also interesting to know, how the decision depends on the screen (matte, glossy) and on the environment (indoor, outdoor,...). In my case it is a Dell Latitude ATG which has a slightly glossy screen (not matte, but not a mirror). I use it indoors in office, in dark rooms and also outdoors.

In my case I first thought, that black font on white background is the best because the white background reduces reflections due to the glossy screen. And because black on white seems to be a high contrast. However it seems that the bright white tires the eyes...

I should point out, that I am not interested in personal opinions but in scientific evidence or at least in reasonable generally accepted guidelines based on experience.

Comment: I like the [solarized colour scheme](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) which I use for the editor and as dircolors.

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: The close vote is for "not constructive," ie., likely to elicit opinions rather than facts. Not mine, btw, I think the fact that you asked for evidence accompanying any answers clearly mitigates that.

Comment: I actually cast one of the close votes - it's a good question but not really on topic for U&L, since it's about color, human color perception, and eye health.

Comment: @jw013 ...but it's also about computers and in particular linux programs. You may say it's about the "computer-human interface", so I doesn't think that it's off-topic...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Taken from the [solorized home page](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized):

> Black text on white from a computer display is akin to reading a book in direct sunlight and tires the eye.
>   Solarized reduces brightness contrast but, unlike many low contrast colorschemes, retains contrasting hues (based on colorwheel relations) for syntax highlighting readability.

Comment: +1. As far as I know Solarized is the only color scheme that has been *engineered*. It's arguable that Solarized is best because science makes it so.

Comment: @bahamat actually that makes sense. I'm gonna give it a try. I love Monokai, but the argument they [Solarized] give is unbeatable.

Comment: It's been meticulously engineered..to have properties..but none of those have been mentioned as being good for the eyes. Rather, they're based on what the designer of solarized finds/found soothing.

Comment: After looking into this, this is really not a great argument. The question is what is an objectively good colour theme, Just picking colors that are mathematically far apart is not engineering for anything other than numerically far apart colors. Our vision is not symmetrically identical on all metrics, so why would we want a color theme to be so?